# Does Dart provide an easy-to-use Linked List?

Tags: dart

I have an algorithm that, for performance reasons, should use a *linked list*. I want constant time appending and removal of elements from the list, and I'll never need to find a specific element by index.

I see Dart has a `LinkedList` ([API docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-collection/LinkedList-class.html)) in `dart:collection`, but that requires all entries to subclass `LinkedListEntry`. I don't control the elements I need to put into the list, and I don't want to create wrappers.

What are my options in the core Dart SDK?

Comment: I suspect the answer is "use Queue", but still curious. The Queue API docs don't have details on usage costs.

Comment: The `ListQueue` documentation says: "Keeps a cyclic buffer of elements, and grows to a larger buffer when it fills up. This guarantees constant time peek and remove operations, and amortized constant time add operations." and `DoubleLinkedQueue` says "Allows constant time add, remove-at-ends and peek operations." - The Queue interface doesn't say anything since sub-implementations may differ.

Comment: Thanks @lrn. Reading about Queue didn't point me to ListQueue or DoubleLinkedQueue. I wonder if we can link (haha get it?) the two in the docs.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17384

Comment: I've always found the LinkedList implementation wrong. Java's LinkedList is the correct way, it provides the List interface without further limitations, which the Dart LinkedList does not. I don't think anyone will ever use LinkedList over Queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add and remove at both ends, you want a `Queue`. You can either use the `ListQueue` (which is the default that you get when using `new Queue()`) or the `DoubleLinkedQueue`. 
The former only guarantees amortized constant time operations for adding and removing at the ends, while the latter has absolute guarantees. The `ListQueue` sometimes need to grow its backing-store on an add, which takes linear time, but it only happens when the list is full, and it does the traditional growing-by-doubling to guarantee amortized constant operation.

If you only want to add and remove at the end (a stack, basically), the normal list should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a reusable wrapper instead of making each value a subclass of LinkedListEntry

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class MyLinkedListEntry<T> extends LinkedListEntry {
  T value;
  MyLinkedListEntry(this.value);
  @override
  String toString() => '${super.toString()}: ${value}';
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  var l = new LinkedList();

  var s = new MyLinkedListEntry<String>("SomeString");
  l.add(s);
  s.insertAfter(new MyLinkedListEntry<int>(125));

  l.forEach((e) => print(e));
}
```

Comment: True, but if possible I want to avoid wrappers. :)

Comment: LinkedList elements need next/previous pointers. There can't be a way where you don't implement `LinkedListEntry` or use a wrapper that does. A queue (DoubleLinkedQueue not ListQueue) does it that way behind the scene. It's a wrapper to hide the  LinkedListEntryWrapper ;-)